# How to compare ctime properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program that gets the modified date/time of directories and files.  I then want to get the date/time from 30 seconds ago and compare that to the modified date/time.

If the modified time is less than 30 seconds ago, I want to trigger an alert.  My code is triggering alert even if the modified time occurred more than 30 seconds ago.

Is there a way I can only trigger an alert if the modification occurred less than 30 seconds ago?

```
import os.path
import time, stat
import sys

share_dir = 'C:/mydir'
source_dir  = r'' + share_dir + '/'

def trigger():
    print("Triggered")

def check_dir():
    while True:
        for currentdir, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
            for file in files:
                currentfile = os.path.join(currentdir, file)

                # get modified time for files
                ftime = os.stat(currentfile )[stat.ST_MTIME]
                past = time.time() - 30  # last 30 seconds
                if time.ctime(ftime) >= time.ctime(past):
                    print(time.ctime(ftime) + " > " + time.ctime(past))
                    print("Found modification in last 30 seconds for file =>", currentfile, time.ctime(ftime))
                    trigger()
                    sys.exit()
                else:
                    print('No recent modifications.' + currentfile)
            for folder in dirs:
                currentfolder = os.path.join(currentdir, folder)

                # get modified time for directories
                dtime = os.stat(currentfolder)[stat.ST_MTIME]
                past = time.time() - 30  # last 30 seconds
                if time.ctime(dtime) >= time.ctime(past):
                    print(time.ctime(dtime) + " > " + time.ctime(past))
                    print("Found modification in last 30 seconds for folder =>", currentfolder, time.ctime(dtime))            
                    trigger()
                    sys.exit()
                else:
                    print('No recent modifications: ' + currentfolder)
        time.sleep(4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_dir()
```

Comment: Didn't you mean to use `dtime` for directories?

Comment: Yes, good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing this on a large scale file system. I personally use SQLite3 and round the `mtime` of the file (I had weird things happen using any other sort of operation and it was more consistent).

I'm also unsure why you're not just doing a pure math solution. Take the current time, take the `mtime` of the file, find the difference between them and if it's less than or equal to thirty, you get a hit.

I redid some of the code. I recommend trying this:

```
import os.path
import time, stat
import sys 

def trigger():
    print("Triggered")

def check_dir(source_dir):
    for currentdir, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
        for file in files:
            currentfile = os.path.join(currentdir, file)

            # get modified time for files
            ftime = os.path.getmtime(currentfile)
            if time.time() - ftime <= 30: 
                print("Found modification in last 30 seconds for file =>", currentfile, time.ctime(ftime))
                trigger()
                exit(0)

            else:
                print('No recent modifications.' + currentfile)

        for folder in dirs:
            currentfolder = os.path.join(currentdir, folder)

            # get modified time for directories
            dtime = os.stat(currentfolder)[stat.ST_MTIME]
            if time.time() - dtime <= 30: 
                print("Found modification in last 30 seconds for folder =>", currentfolder, time.ctime(dtime))
                trigger()
                exit(0)

            else:
                print('No recent modifications: ' + currentfolder)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_dir('yourdirectoryhere')
```

Did some light testing on my own system and it seemed to work perfectly. Might want to add back the while loop but it should work.